# How to check if two .wav file contains the same sound data?

Tags: c#, audio

Here is an example, I'll try to make it as simple as possible.

I have 2 .wav/.mp3 sound file "A" and "B".
"A" sounds like this: "asdfasdafasfsaf **DATA** sdafsfdafsa".
"B" sounds like this: "**DATA**".

Now my question is, how to check if "A" contains "B"?
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and coding in C#. Is it even possible without a 3rd party sofware?
*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a trivial matter however:

- If both wav files have the same sample frequency, you're good to go. If not, you have to resample to correspond (either with a tool or programmatically)
- Figure out where the actual data starts for both files (this can vary greatly, read about wav header sizes and how to detect them)
- Read data for both files into byte arrays

The above is pretty much step 0.

- Your "sample" that you'll be looking for, has a length. That length will be a sliding window over your target byte array.
- If you're content to search for the exact same sample (some part of A sounds EXACTLY like B) then you can do a dumb compare of your sliding window content to your reference sample (byte compare). If, however, you want to look for your sample in a mixdown target wav (mixed in with other sounds or layers so some part of A has B in it but it's just one of x things you hear at the time indices where B occurs) then from what I understand you're heading for Fast and/or Discrete Fourier Transforms, Hidden Markov Models or any number of algorithms for pattern recognition. There are undoubtedly countless people here who are way smarter than me who can actually say sensible things when it comes to math. Just... not me.

Up until the math part, it's pretty straightforward but the real magic starts when you implement the algorithm(s) you settle upon. You can, of course, take this as far as you want, depending on your requirements and your math background / skillset / patience / ...

A small side note: "is this possible without 3rd party software" is rarely a really pertinent question. 3rd party software is not some black magic, it's just software written by people like you and me. The difference is, that it's sometimes written by very smart people (often plural) and often developed and tested and perfected over an extended period of time so if the question is "can it be done" then almost always "yes". If the question is "can I reproduce a complete, complex and high-performance library by myself in a small amount of time" ...well... maybe I guess.